# spring MVC 3 get request returning code 304 incorrectly from ie

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, http, spring-mvc

i have a spring MVC 3 website with a get mapping to a url site.com/../someItems

the problem is that the get request always returns Http code 304 when performed from ie 9, which it shouldnt be since the content is actually modified. Even after sending a post request, spring still returns a code of 304 on the next get.

The problem is that this works ok in chrome and firefox  but in ie 9, the get request never gets the items updated after the post request.

Does anyone know what may be going on wrong here? Why it isnt returning a code 200 instead of 304?

I am using the latest jquery version to perform the get/post requests. IE is performing the post requests fine, since I can see the update happening on chrome (or if i close ie and open it again)

```
$.get("someItems", function(data){
    $('#someDiv').html(data);
});
```

Looking at the actual get request being generated, the request from firefox and chrome includes the cookie, while the request from ie does not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldnt find a way to disable caching with the shorthand notation so I ended up with this

```
$.ajax({
          url: "someItems",
          data: '',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqHXR){
              $('#someDiv').html(data);
          }
    });
```

and this seems to have resolved the problem and the cookies are now being sent with the request.

Answer (score 1):

This is because IE 9 caches your Ajax requests:

http://www.dashbay.com/2011/05/internet-explorer-caches-ajax/

you should use "CacheBuster" technic:

```
$.get("someItems? "+ Math.random(), function(data){
    $('#someDiv').html(data);
});
```

It will create different request each time.

Comment: The caching part is ture but i dont know if the random number part is a good thing since they might be repeated so there are no guarantees

Comment: This is not an issue,it will bring you random number between 0 and 1 cache will expire before random number will repeat itself.

Comment: this is a hack and has negative consequences as well, as highlighted in the same article that you linked to. It will cache all the requests and leave less space for actual requests that need to be cached and the number can interfere in the URL parsing since this is a rest service

Comment: well, the best solution is not to use IE at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Check what realy gets posted by either F12 in ie or using a tool like http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/.

The standalone version of ieinspector can capture traffic of Firefox and IE, so its easier to compare. They have a trial version you can use. If you cant find the problem post the captured traffic here.

Comment: IE was caching the request. It did not send the 'cookie' header in the request while chrome and firefox did. For some reason, ie enables caching by default while ff and chrome dont. look at my answer for what worked.